# Weird error in my simple OpenMP Programm (using C)

Tags: c, recursion, openmp

I'm getting this error when I'm trying to compile my C program:

```
omptest.c: In function ‘int ack(int, int)’:
omptest.c:13:23: error: invalid form of ‘#pragma omp atomic’ before ‘;’ token
   ans = ack(m-1,1);}
                   ^
omptest.c:18:31: error: invalid form of ‘#pragma omp atomic’ before ‘;’ token
   ans = ack(m-1, ack(m,n-1));
```

I don't have any idea how this error could occur. Here's my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>

int ack(int m, int n)
{
  int ans;
  if (m == 0)
    ans = n+1;
  else if (n == 0)
    #pragma omp task
    {
      #pragma omp atomic
      ans = ack(m-1,1);}
  else
  #pragma omp task
  {
    #pragma omp atomic
    ans = ack(m-1, ack(m,n-1));}
  #pragma omp taskwait
  return (ans);
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
  int i,j;

  for (i=1; i<6; i++)
    for (j=0;j<6; j++)
      printf("ackerman (%d,%d) is: %d\n",i,j, ack(i,j));
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which compiler do you use? Visual Studio imposes some restrictions on `atomic`, restricting the openmp spec (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5fhhcxk3.aspx))

Comment: Maybe this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14016026/openmp-and-pragma-omp-atomic) may be very useful in your case?

Comment: I am using the g++ compiler (g++ omptest.c -o omptest -fopenmp -lpthread)

Comment: @Bentoy13 I'm sorry I don't see how this post is usefull. I'm very new in OpenMP

Comment: Oops, wrong link (that one was more about the VC problem). Here is a [post on OpenMP forum](http://openmp.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=1385&p=5392#p5392) about what to be done in case of recursive functions.

Comment: I wrote the Program acording to this pdf: http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall10/cos597C/docs/Cilk.pdf I did the exact thing like on page 11

Comment: In fact, I realize that the core of your function is not parallel. You don't compute two calls of `ack` in parallel at all because of the `if` construct, so there is no parallelization there. Besides that point, the [OpenMP reference](http://www.openmp.org/mp-documents/OpenMP3.1.pdf) says that `The taskwait directive may not be
used in place of the statement following an if, while, do, switch, or label`

Comment: There is one big difference: in the pdf you are using, all openmp tasks are inside the same `else` block, not one on the if and one on the else. In the pdf, you want to parallelize 2 instructions, whereas in your case there is no parallel thing to do.

Comment: So, is there another way to a parallelization?

Comment: Concerning the `ack` function, I don't have any idea, sorry. And this [answer of this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/961183/1507014) is quite interesting for your problem: the function is almost untractable for `m>4`...

Comment: Do you think I could have better chances with Cilk?

Comment: Honestly, I don't think so. The Ackermann function is a completely sequential function by essence, no parallelization scheme seems to be applied there. So it's not a matter of programming language here, this function is just untractable except for m from 0 to 4.